# Automation of docker commands

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I want to do the automation of docker commands so that ,

I can verify the docker commands to verify the sanity .

I just need to know if any plugins are available for this purpose, or If I have to start from the scratch in which language I can write ? How to start it initially?

Comment: Do you know Dockerfiles to automate the build process of Docker images?

Comment: I am targeting to complete the commands starting from Ubuntu vm creation , then later install docker on the created VM, running the images etc etc .,many scenarios in one shot ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to automate the creation and provisioning of a VM with Docker, you should take a look at Vagrant (and maybe Puppet).

## Vagrant

Vagrant is a tool to create VMs. You find it at http://www.vagrantup.com/. It works basically like this: You install Vagrant and a VM like VirtualBox. Then you create a file called Vagrantfile which describes your VM. For my Docker environment, I am using a file which looks like this:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "99designs/ubuntu-saucy-docker"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://vagrantcloud.com/99designs/ubuntu-saucy-docker/version/2/provider/virtualbox.box"

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 8080
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 4243, host: 4243
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9000, host: 9000
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5000, host: 5000

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=777"]

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2024"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "2"]
  end

  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "add_docker_to_sudo.sh"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "disable_friewall.sh"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "set_nls_lang.sh"

end
```

The file describes your VM. It defines the image installed to your VM (maybe the boot2docker image), open ports, folders of your host available in your VM and so on. It can also define scripts which are run when the VM is up. In my example, I am running three shell scripts when the VM is up to add Docker to sudo, disable the firewall (hahaha) and set a environment variable I need. You can to anything here. If shell commands are not enough, take a look at (e.g.) Puppet (http://puppetlabs.com/).

You just call `vagrant up` to create your VM and `vagrant ssh` to get access to it. You can just destroy it and create it again anytime you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the very useful information. On a side note, have you tried doing the same thing in node .js framework , just a random thought and different ways of doing it?Is it feasible in node .js as well

Comment: Vagrant is written in Ruby, so the syntax is just Ruby. I don't know any alternative which uses Node.js.